# Convert double to double with one decimal point and one decimal place?

Tags: java, double, decimal, rounding

I want to round any double to a double with the format of one decimal point and one decimal place so 29575.347434 would be 2.3.

Tried doing this with decimalFormat but when i try #.# i just get a string in the format of 29575.3 with a , and i have no idea idea how to cut off all decimal points while keeping my value a double.

Comment: You would probably have to treat it as a string -- 29575.347434 does not round to 2.3 in any standard mathematical way.... As for keeping it a double, just parse it back.

Comment: So you want to get the leftmost integer digit, followed by a decimal point, followed by the leftmost fractional digit?

Comment: @Cinnam yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the number as `String`, take the first digit and the digit after `'.'`. For non-negative numbers that would be

```
String s = Double.toString(29575.347434);
double d = Double.parseDouble(s.charAt(0) + "." + s.charAt(s.indexOf('.') + 1));
System.out.println(d); // 2.3
```

If the number can be negative, you would have to correct the code for the possible minus sign.

Comment: I don't think this would round the fractional portion of the number, just trim it.

Comment: @KyleGowen You're right, but this seems to be what OP wants.

Comment: Oh.  He said he wanted to round his double.  So I assumed he wanted rounding to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by using the modulo operator %.

It looks like your decimal formatting is working with #.#.  That will give you the whole number and one decimal place.  You can then do your number 29575.3 % 10 and get 5.3.

Try this code and see:

```
System.out.println(29575.3d % 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Number(parseFloat(29575.347434).toFixed(1))
```

You could also pass a **string** , because `parseFloat()` would convert it to **number**, then trunkate to wished **decimal** (output is **string** again), then convert back to **decimal** by function `Number()`.

Works for me.